# Ternary for the following code

Tags: php

I got the following code and Is it possible to do the else condition as a ternary:

```
if (condition) {
   //do something
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['A'])) {
        header("Location: /LocationA");
        exit;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['B'])) {
        header("Location: /LocationB");
        exit;
    }
}
```

I tried doing the following, but I'm not sure if I am right:

```
 isset($_POST['A']) ? header("Location: /LocationA")
        : header("Location: /LocationB}");
 exit;
```

**I only need to change the ELSE on the statement.** So it's gonna be like :

```
if (condition) {
 //do something
} else {
 //ternary
}
```

Comment: "but I'm not sure if I am right" test it and see if you are right or not

Comment: There's a third condition in the first code block: neither 'A' nor 'B' is set, at which point there will be no call to `header`.

Comment: also what's the need behind converting the ordinary if statement into a ternary ?

Comment: @hassan I tried and and It work but I'm just a bit doubting it. Someone suggested it to me that its better if its on ternary to make the code nicer. :/

Comment: Make code "nicer" is subjective. For me, it is better to be long code, but readable and easy to maintain because in 3 months when you re-visit your old code, you will feel the pain.

Comment: it's a good choice in it's place :-)

Comment: Considering that [header()](http://php.net/header) doesn't return anything, you'd be using ternary operator for the sake of using it (don't forget to add a `// Thug life` comment). I would, however, reduce one level of nesting with the not so cool but but nonetheless practical `elseif` clause, or remove duplication by moving the common `exit` downwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but I'm not sure if I am right

**You are not right.**

The [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (`?:`) is an operator. As [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) says:

> An operator is something that takes one or more values (or expressions, in programming jargon) and yields another value (so that the construction itself becomes an expression).

Please note the words "values" and "expression" in the sentence above.

The PHP function [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) doesn't return anything. The call `header(...)` doesn't have a value, it has only side-effects (it modifies the status of the program).

You are trying to replace an [`if` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) with an operator. They are different things, have different purposes in the language and follow different rules. Changing one for another doesn't work.

---

The expression you posted:

```
isset($_POST['A']) ? header("Location: /LocationA") 
    : header("Location: /LocationB}");
```

doesn't have the same effect as the `if` statement you are trying to replace.
There is an `if (isset($_POST['B']))` in the original piece of code that is missing in the rewritten code.

Without caring about `$_POST['B']`, you can write the code like this:

```
if (condition) {
   //do something
} else {
    header(isset($_POST['A'] ? 'Location: /LocationA' : 'Location: /LocationB');
    exit();
}
```

Or, even shorter:

```
header('Location: ' . (isset($_POST['A']) ? '/LocationA' : '/LocationB'));
```

Comment: This is so accurate sir, I don't know why that someone is so obsessed with ternary.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
isset($_POST['A']) 
? 
header("Location: /LocationA");  
: 
header("Location: /LocationB");  

exit;
```

i think it works. :)

Comment: One `exit` is enough

Comment: @samayo after header i don't think that you even need exit :-)

Comment: Exam question: what will `$x` contain afterwards? You must figure out without running the code :)

Comment: @hassan Sometime you do. In-case header is already, it will not redirect and will only continue to parse the rest of your code. If you want to avoid this you can use header/exit